# Assigning $Scope variable inside DBService

Tags: angularjs

I have the following Code:

```
 var $pid = 1;    
 $scope.records = [];

 DBService.getUserById($pid)

  .then(function(data) {
  $scope.records = data;
  console.log("OUTSIDE",$scope.records); // Shows [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
});
console.log("OUTSIDE:",$scope.records); // // Shows []
```

Why is the last log empty? 
And how do I get the callback data inside my $scope variable?

Answer (score 2):

The last log is outside of your then function and occurs immediately, before the service call has been completed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that it is asyncronous. But how do I wait for the call the end and save the data into my $scope?

Comment: What you're doing within the then function is correct for that. If you need other things to happen after the data has been retrieved you can call that code from within the then function as well.

Comment: can you please post an example? I want to wait for the call to finish and then assign the result to the variable

Comment: I guess, I'm not completely following you, because the way I'm reading this, that's exactly what your line $scope.records = data does. If you're wanting to assign the value to a plain old variable, you could define the variable before your call to DBService and assign the data to that variable within the then function, but it still won't become immediately available. Are you getting a response object back rather than the data you expect and that's the real issue? I guess I'm unclear about what end result you're looking for. Maybe reword the question?